# Blazor: render component without cshtml

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, storyblok

I'm currently trying to implement a [open-source SDK](https://github.com/adliance/Storyblok) that was made for Storyblok CMS. This SDK was made to be used with Razor Pages, but I'm trying to implement it in my Blazor project.

The problem I'm running in to is that the SDK middleware is trying to render the *view*, but Blazor uses Razor components. The middleware tries to do it like this:

```cs
return executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
```

This throws the following exception:
`InvalidOperationException: The view 'Page' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Page.cshtml  /Views/Shared/Page.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Page.cshtml`. This makes sense, since I don't use Views but Components (`.razor` files).

I feel like I've been searching the entire internet, but I really don't know how to fix this issue. Is it even possible to render a component? Is this even fix-able?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck here configuring the middleware needed for blazor components on another plattform.

[Walkthrough integrating blazor to existing asp.net core app](https://waelkdouh.medium.com/integrating-blazor-components-into-existing-asp-net-core-mvc-applications-b1a2aec4ac1f)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. The external library is just a class library with logic to render the views. The solution I'm looking for can render the Blazor components via code.